# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process not sure why this error getting

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, httphandler

I have written a http handler program which will download pdf document from sharepoint and the downloaded document will be sent to the end user browser. The downloaded location is "C:\Windows\Temp" . My program is working fine in chrome browser but sometimes not always in IE9 or IE10 getting error **"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"** . My concern is: is it because of downloaded location path "C:\Windows\Temp" as it is  system folder but if this is the issue why its working in stable manner in chrome? Or flaws in my code? I tried to apply thread for 3 ms but it didn't work shows the same error. Here is my code:

```
SPFile myFile = Web.GetFile(Context.Request.Url.ToString());
byte[] bytescontent=myFile.OpenBinary();
string myDownloadedFilePath = @"C:\Windows\Temp";
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(bytescontent);
FileStream stream = new FileStream(myDownloadedFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, stream);
//iterate through all pages in source pdf
for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
{
//Rectangle class in iText represent geomatric representation... in this case, rectanle object would contain page geomatry
Rectangle pageRectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex);
//pdfcontentbyte object contains graphics and text content of page returned by pdfstamper
PdfContentByte pdfData = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(pageIndex);
//create fontsize for watermark
pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 40);
//create new graphics state and assign opacity
PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.4F;
//set graphics state to pdfcontentbyte
pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);
//set color of watermark
pdfData.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
//indicates start of writing of text
pdfData.BeginText();
//show text as per position and rotation
pdfData.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "My Custom Text", pageRectangle.Width / 2, pageRectangle.Height / 2, 45);
//call endText to invalid font set
pdfData.EndText();
}
//close stamper and output filestream
pdfStamper.Close();
stream.Close();
//Thread.sleep(3000);
Here I am sending back the downloaded document to the end user as per MimeType.
```

Comment: Try calling stream.Dispose() instead of close

Comment: I tried with both stream.Close() and stream.Dispose() but didn't work.

Comment: Is PdfReader  an IDisposable, you might need to dispose that one as well